# How to render html file from directory public in nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt3

At a specific application URL, I need to render not a nuxt page, but an html file that is located in the public folder (/public/page.html). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set up one or more of your routes in the server directory to read an HTML file and return the contents, and Nuxt/Nitro will serve that.

```
// server/routes/test.ts
// This assumes that you have a page called 'test-page.html'
// in your project's 'public' directory.

import fs from 'node:fs';

export default defineEventHandler(() => {
  return fs.readFileSync('./public/test-page.html');
});
```

You can read more about creating server routes [in the Nuxt 3 docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server).

Now, it's worth noting this bit from the Nuxt 3 docs about the `public` directory:

> Files contained within the `public/` directory are served at the root and are not modified by the build process. This is suitable for files that have to keep their names (e.g. `robots.txt`) or likely won't change (e.g. `favicon.ico`).

This means that if you place a file named `test-page.html` in your `public/` directory in a Nuxt 3 project, going to `{host}/test-page.html` will load that file as well. Depending on your purposes, that may not be ideal. You may want to consider placing those HTML files elsewhere that `fs` can still read them from, but that Nuxt 3 doesn't automatically serve them from.

If you want to tinker with a working demo, you can find one here:
https://github.com/niko-chaffinchicas/test-nuxt-serve-html